# accessing a pointer member variable in derived class

Tags: c++

I have following code:

```
class B{
    protected:
    X *x;
    public:
    function(char *data){
        // access x
        // works fine
    } 
};

class D: public B {
    function2(char *data)
    {
            // access x
            // gets garbage
    } 
};
```

I have a member variable which is pointer. moreover this pointer is inside  `"data"`  but when i access in class D it shows garbage.

can some body please help me...

Comment: "moreover this pointer is inside "data" say what?

Comment: The pointer member by itself is useless unless you really make it point to some valid object of type `X`.You do not show that part of code, particularly the constructor or the member function which does this.Without seeing that code it is impossible to say *Why?*, If you are not doing that at all then **you should!**

Comment: say : x = (X *) (data + 23 + 26);

Comment: please post the real code. this can't be compiled either.

Comment: i am not able to post the complete code. i can not answer my question and can not post complete in comment but its just a small packet parser. so char* data is unsigned char * and X may be (ip_header *) kind of data structures or even just simple integer values. when these values are accessed in function (whether called from main program or derived class), they work fine but when i access them in derived class they present garbage value.

Comment: @user1759515 You have a bug in your program. Without seeing more code it's completely impossible to say where it is. Rest assured though the bug isn't in the code you posted (it never is).

Comment: if you have garbage into `function2(char *data)`, perhaps, your `x` is uninitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put on my psychic debugging hat, and come to the conclusion you're probably doing something like this:

```
class Packet
{
public:
  Gizmo* gizmo_;
};

class Processor
{
public:
  void ProcessPacket(char* packet);
};

// ...

Packet packet;
// packet filled with goodies

Processor proc;
proc.ProcessPacket(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packet.gizmo_));
```

Am I right?

If so, my guess is that the `Gizmo` you're pointing to has somehow fallen out of scope -- thereby becoming destroyed -- or you performed the cast incorrectly.

Comment: yeah not complete. Packet is base class with ProcessPacket Function, and Processor class is derived from Packet class. i created an object of class Processor and called "ProcessPacket". and then *gizmo is going corrupt